# Django backend, make email or phone required

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is an email automatically set to required when using Django?

I'm trying to build an API where email or phone is required.

This is the backend I built

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from accounts.models import User

class UserBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs['username']
        phone_number = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']
        try:
            app_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if app_user.check_password(password) is True :
                return app_user
        
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            app_user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
            if app_user .check_password(password) is True :
                return app_user 

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

[image]

Can't seem to get rid of email

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate(self, attrs):

    phone_number_ = attrs.get('phone_number', '')
    email_ = attrs.get('email', '') # get - Provide defualt param is email not inserted
    username_ = attrs.get('username', '')
    
    if phone_number_ == '' and  email_== '':
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Enter email or phone')

    elif User.objects.filter(email=email_).exists():
        if email_ != '': 
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {'email',('Email is already in use')})

    elif User.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number_).exists():
        if phone_number_ != '':
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {'phone_number',('Phone Number is already in use')})
            
    elif User.objects.filter(username=username_).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {'username',('Username is already in use')})

    return super().validate(attrs)
```

Added this to my serializer. I'm not a very good coder but all the changes I made, made sense to me. It also seems to work perfectly, will update if I find bugs.

Phone number doesn't have to be unique don't know why?